# why dictionary.get(node.next) is not equivalent to dictionary[node.next] in this case?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am solving LeetCode NO. 138 and have two answers shown in the text below. Version 1 works but version 2. doesn't.

I am wondering why I need to use `dictionary.get()` method to assess the corresponding value of a node. Is it because we may end up with a None node that is undefined in the key pool of the dictionary `d`? Thanks.

Version 1.

```
"""
# Definition for a Node.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x, next=None, random=None):
        self.val = int(x)
        self.next = next
        self.random = random
"""
class Solution:
def copyRandomList(self, head: 'Node') -> 'Node':
    d = dict()
    m = head
    while m:
        d[m] = Node(m.val)
        m = m.next
    n = head
    while n:
        d[n].next = d.get(n.next)
        d[n].random = d.get(n.random)
        n = n.next
    return d[head]
```

Version 2.

```
class Solution:
def copyRandomList(self, head: 'Node') -> 'Node':
    d = dict()
    m = head
    while m:
        d[m] = Node(m.val)
        m = m.next
    n = head
    while n:
        d[n].next = d[n.next]
        d[n].random = d[n.random]
        n = n.next
    return d[head]
```

Comment: the usual "get returns None when key not found whereas [] throws an exception"

Comment: Does version 2 throw a `KeyError` ? else both are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two loops. The first one loops until `m.next` is "falsy"

```
while m:
    d[m] = Node(m.val)
    m = m.next
```

that loop fills the `.next` field:

```
while n:
    d[n].next = d.get(n.next)
    d[n].random = d.get(n.random)
    n = n.next
```

if `n.next` isn't in `d` then `d[n].next` is `None`. That ends the "linked list".

If we had used `d[n.next]` here it would have thrown a `KeyError`: not what we want.